# How to get result from a dictionary with lists as the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a JSON file with n number of dictionaries as listed below in the snippet. I am trying to fetch the value against the key but it fails in my code when the value is defined as a list like in the below example for key `affected_packages`. I tried to check why my code fails, so it looks like it pulls no data out of it this fails. I just see two brackets `[]` as output instead of `"thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_1","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_2","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_3","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el7_9"`

```
{"bugzilla_description":"CVE-2021-23992 Mozilla: A crafted OpenPGP key with an invalid user ID could be used to confuse the user","cvss_score":null,"cvss_scoring_vector":null,"CWE":"CWE-347","affected_packages":["thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_1","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_2","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_3","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el7_9"],"resource_url":"https://access.redhat.com/hydra/rest/securitydata/cve/CVE-2021-23992.json","cvss3_scoring_vector":"CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:N/I:N/A:L","cvss3_score":"4.3"}
```

I am doing like below in my code as I need to prepare a worksheet. Sample snippet:

```
for i in range(offs):
    ws.cell(row=r+1+i,column=2).value = v['current'][i]
    if 'affected_packages' in list(tmp1.keys()):
          ws.cell(row=r+1+index1,column=11).value = tmp1['affected_packages']
          print("affected_packages done")
    if 'advisories' in list(tmp1.keys()):
          ws.cell(row=r+1+index2,column=13).value = tmp1['advisories']
          print("advisories done")
```

Is there a way I can pull the value correctly for those defined as a list in the dictionary? I need a way so that it won't hamper my existing logic to pull value for normal key: value since while looking up into my JSON file.

So need something which can fulfil both whether my value in the dictionary is as a list or not as a list and I can get value against the keys in my json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can test the type of a variable using

```
if type(some_variable) == list: 
    # do what you need to do
```

You do mention that your code breaks, and I guess it's because inserting into a cell expects a String, not the list you pass in the line

```
          ws.cell(row=r+1+index1,column=11).value = tmp1['affected_packages']
```

So how do we get a string out of a list of strings? It's pretty easy using the join method.

```
my_list = ["thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_1","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_2","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_3","thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el7_9"]

as_one_string = ", ".join(my_list)
print(as_one_string)
# Prints out 'thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_1, thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_2, thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el8_3, thunderbird-0:78.9.1-1.el7_9'
```

So combining the two ideas:

```
    if 'affected_packages' in list(tmp1.keys()):
          ws.cell(row=r+1+index1,column=11).value = tmp1['affected_packages'] if type(tmp1['affected_packages']) != list else ", ".join(tmp1['affected_packages'])
          print("affected_packages done")
```

Quick feedback because I can't comment yet: Please always include an error message and/or the output you get when running your code when you ask a question

Comment: just to add here, it picks blank value - The output goes as []

Comment: As in the cell in your work sheet is empty? or a []

Comment: Also I made a typo in the last line of my code, fixed now

Comment: it goes as [ ] instead of required value

Comment: Can you update your question with the code where you define tmp1? Also when you say it goes as [] is that in the worksheet, or when you print tmp1['affected_packages'] in the code?

Comment: Here is the code using which I define tmp1 from my json file:
  ```
for d in dictlist:
      if d["CVE"] == rhelcve:
        doi = d # copy dict_of_interest in a variable
        outf = open("/Users/rajesh/Downloads/outputfile.json", "w")
        outstr = json.dumps(doi)
        outf.write(outstr)
        #print(tmp1)
        outf.close()
        tmp1 = json.loads(outstr) 
        return tmp1
        break
```

Comment: Cool, you should probably add that to your initial question :) 

What does printing tmp1 at the end of that loop give you?

Comment: The loop is done as I need to go through my whole json file and populate in worksheet. The snippet I pasted is just one of a dictionary from my json file. There are n number of dictionaries which I need to look up based on a value. So for every value I search in json file, pull the dictionary in tmp1 and then based on tmp1 data update my worksheet.

Comment: I've seen the new code you've shared. If k prints [], then that entry in the dictionary is indeed an empty list. Could there be some issues that do not have affected packages? Might be helpful to print the whole dictionary for you. 

In all cases, the issue at this point seems to be either in how you parse the file, or in the fact that the json has some empty entries where it shouldn't

Comment: yeah I see in the one I see error its empty, probably it fails on worksheet. Thanks for the catch. Any idea how to fix it if value is empty then should not fail or update some n/a sort of value

Comment: It doesn't fail, [] is still recognized as a list, and ", ".join([ ]) will give you an empty string which makes sense to put in the worksheet if there is indeed no data. 

Part of the stuff that confused me in your code shared earlier was your use of returns and breaks. At this point are you able to see multiple rows in your output? I'm thinking you might only be writing 1 of your dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second problem, when you don't know if it is a list or something else, you can just check the type, maybe like this:

```
if type(tmp1['affected_packages']) == list:
    # process the list
else:
    # process other types
```

Since you don't know the data type, having this explicit type check seems necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you just need to determine if a value in dict is list. You can do that as below:

```
for i in d.items(): # gets key, value as a tuple. 
   if isinstance(i[1],list):
       print('its a list, process it accordingly')
   else:
       print('Not a list')
```

Comment: No I need to print a list in a way I am doing for non-list values as you can see in my code snippet